# Preview is not working in page section in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm not sure if this is related to WP 3.9 or not, but I just updated to 3.9 and then tried to edit a page. When I hit "preview", it opens the actual page which does not reflect any changes. I cannot see the changes unless I update - save the page.

It used to not be this way. Its been a few days since I edited a page, but preview worked then when I was on WP 3.8.2 Is this a bug in the new version? What can I do to get preview back?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a number of things:

Firstly I would add this code to your wp-config.php file (located at the root of your website)

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

This should display an error, to give you help of identifying the issue.

Hope this helps?

Comment: Nothing in your server log files?

Comment: Yes there is nothing in server log.